# When is a higher return not desireable in a Retirement Fund?

Tags: australia, investment-strategies, shares, smsf

I have been back-testing some share investment strategies for my SMSF (self managed retirement fund) and have narrowed it down to two strategies that have consistently performed the best over a 3 year period. A summary of the two strategies is summarised in the table below:

[image: Investment Strategies]

The starting capital for both strategies is $50,000 and the chosen strategy would only form a portion of the total investments in the fund which would also include some direct property investments, some cash and possibly some bonds.

Strategy A had a Compounded Annual Return (CAR) of 25.5% and almost doubled the initial investment in 3 years compared to a whopping CAR of 41.1% for Strategy B which almost tripled the initial investment over the same period. Looking simply at this information it seems like a no brainer to choose Strategy B. However, being a retirement fund, would it still be wise to choose Strategy B over Strategy A?

**Notes Regarding the Strategies:** In the back-testing for both strategies all trades where bought at the open on the next day once a signal was given and a 20% trailing stop loss was automatically placed on each open trade. I also plan to test both of these strategies going forward over the next 12 months in a virtual account to verify the results and avoid curve fitting the back-tested results. Once this is done and the results are confirmed I could start trading a real account in either 2016 or 2017 (depending on when I set up my SMSF), so if the results do not correspond to the back-testing I still have a further year available for additional planning.

Comment: What you really want to know to evaluate their suitability are the risks; the likelihood of a significant decline in value, which might leave you much less money for retirement.  You can't directly tell that from past returns, but in general you might expect that an investment that is volatile enough to show huge returns over a fairly short period is also volatile enough to show huge losses.

Comment: @NateEldredge - that is why I have included in the table the maximum drawdown over the 3 years and other relevant information.

Comment: I was going to ask about that too.  You've included the max drawdown and winners/losers ratio, so isn't that your answer?  The reason you might choose A over B is that A has a higher win/loss ratio and lower chance of heavy losses.

Comment: @BrenBarn - I'd be happy with a win ratio of above 50%, so I don't see that as a problem.

Comment: Okay, but it's going to be hard to answer the question if it depends on your personal risk tolerance.  Drawdown and win percentage are some reasons; whether they're reasons you care about isn't something anyone else can answer for you.

Comment: Are you sure period 2012-2014 is representative enough to base of strategy? It might be good to include (at least) the 2007-2008 crash to check what happens if market declines. If you get several false positives in such circumstances and get several 20% hits then you can get to square one quickly.

Comment: @User - that would not have been a problem because my system only trades when the market as a whole is going up. So I would have been out of the stock market from the start of 2008 until mid-2009. In my retirement fund my aim is to invest medium to long term in up-trending stocks in an up-trending market. For my trading outside of my retirement fund I tend to be more aggressive and trade for the shorter to medium term long in up-trending stocks in up-trending markets and short in down-trending stocks in down-trending markets.

Comment: @BrenBarn - the reason the win ratio doesn't bother me is due to the size of the wins compared to the size of the loses. So if my system delivers at least 50% wins I know it will be profitable.

Comment: 3 years seems *really* short for retirement trading backtesting. The last three years have been a ridiculous bull market.

Comment: @radpin - the Australian market has gone up 31% over the last 3 years (that's a CAR of 9.5% p.a.) and has been flat over the last year - so that isn't a "ridiculous bull market" in my opinion. Also as I mentioned above my system would only produce trade signals when the market as a whole is trending up - so I think the last 3 years would be a good representation for back-testing, plus I intend to do a further one to two years of forward testing to make sure there is no curve fitting with the back-testing.

Comment: What is the average duration of your trades for both systems?

Comment: Having a trailing stop loss of 20% most of the positions are open for the medium to long term - from say 6 months to 3+ years - in other words at the end of the 3 years a few positions were still open and had current profits of over 100%.

Comment: It's been over three years since this question was posted.  What type of returns did you get when you put your back-tested strategy into effect.

Comment: @Itsme2003 - my plan to set up a SMSF has been delayed, mainly due to the property market as it has been booming here up until the end of last year, and might take another year or 2 before it reaches a bottom and then I can progress - as the properties where going to be the main investments in the SMSF. In the mean time I have kept running the 2 back-tests in a live simulation. The more conservative option (my preferred choice due to the lower drawdown and higher win size to lost size) has overtaken B. A has currently gone up to $247K, whilst B has lagged behind $229K due to larger drawdowns.

Comment: I have however, started to trade another tested strategy outside of SMSF from February this year. Back-testing for 5 years suggested a CAR of approx. 20%. Since the start of February my return is 12%. However, as I am trading this account on margin (using CFDs) my returns on actual funds invested is 4x that, so approx. 48% in just under 5 months.

Answer (score 1):

If you can travel back in time, and start investing at the start of the period of the back-testing, the strategy with the higher return is better.

Past performance is not a good indicator for future performance, since markets change. But it's often the best we have.

A single 3 year period is not exactly good back-testing for a solid investment strategy. You can improve the back-testing by testing different scenarios instead of just a single 3 year period, and you will notice that in some of them Strategy A will come out on top. Make sure that you use different scenarios for fitting and for testing, otherwise you simply optimize for the testing scenarios. You will also notice that some times both strategies will lose a lot of money. Which strategy you chose then depends on which scenarios you expect to be how likely to come up in the near future, and how much money the strategies gain/lose in each of these scenarios.

Comment: Choosing the strategy with the highest return may not always be the best option, especially when that strategy might be too volatile that it keeps you up at night. Regarding using only 3 years of backtesting - I have already mentioned I will also be doing up to 2 years of forward testing, and that the testing period is a good representation of the strategy because during large market downturns such as the one in 2008, my system does not trade and the stop losses on any open positions would be tightened to protect profits and capital.